# How to sign an XML document in a specific Tag with DocuSign SAPI Local

Tags: docusignapi, cosign-api

The repository I'm using: [Sign-XML](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes/tree/master/dsa-local/C-Sharp-Sign-XML). In the moment I can only sign a XML document in the most external Tag. I need to know how to sign a XML file in a specific Tag. You can see an example bellow:

```
<Tag1>
   <Tag2>
      <Signature>...</Signature>
   </Tag2>
</Tag1>
```

Comment: Are you purposefully using the DSA code? (DocuSign Appliance)? Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to sign a XML document in a specific place.

Comment: you would need to create a visible version of the XML document. HTML. Image. PDF. Word document. XML is not a format DocuSign can sign because there are many different ways to make it look

Comment: unless you want to digitally sign the XML? so it's not modified? that's not the same thing (And it's not in a specific place)

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot create an empty signature field in XML you need to use the SAPISignatureFieldCreateSign function for creating and signing the XML file.

I'm not sure you can sign inside a specific tag,SAPI Local supports attaching a digital signature to XML.